# How to call function when ajax content changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

So i'm working on a shopify site and stuck on a script m writing, the situation is that there is a plugin installed to insert reviews on the site, and the task is to make every user have a "verified buyer" tag just after the user name even if its not a verified user, since the real verified user have a tag through the plugin, the job is to insert it after every user expect those which already have it, I was able to do it using this script -

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){

function addVerified(){

    var list=document.querySelectorAll('display-wrapper .nav-content .reviews-active .review');
    for(let li of list){

        if(!li.classList.contains('hidden')&& (!li.firstElementChild.classList.contains('verified-buyer'))){
            let needElem=li.firstElementChild.children[1].firstElementChild;
            needElem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="label-with-tooltip pull-left">  <span class="y-label>Verified Buyer</span>   </div>'); 

        }
    }
}

addVerified();

});
```

Everything works right expect when pagination below the reviews is used, the content changes and the reviews changes and the function does not work thus making the verified buyer tag removed, I have tried DOMSubtreeModified (made the script stuck in infinite loop), ajaxComplete to execute the function, but nothing have worked so far, I have not much knowledge of javascript I'm still learning, after getting too frustrated I decided to post it here. Please help

Comment: Post the plugin ajax script... And post the HTML markup before and after. What is about the *«pagination»*? No soothsayer here... Please post all that is relevant.

Comment: shopify plugin source code cannot be changed, thats the main problem, the plugins/widgets are online and their source cannot be seen or modified, the HTML does not changes at all, all the content and classes remains same expect the text inside the reviews like the User name and the comments by the user

Comment: Ok... But then post a sample of the affected HTML before and the same sample after.

Comment: As I said there is only changes in the text and no elements, here is the link anyways - shop.outsourcesol.com/products/felted-zebra-skin-grade-b

Comment: Okay... So your function IS working,... But not on page change, right?

Comment: yes,exactly,but the whole page doesnt changes, only the content of the div changes which have the reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... With the rest of your markup I can suggest something.

That is a lie made to customers... I don't like that.

But anyway, here is the way to tweak on it:

```
// Create the element to insert
var fake_verified_buyer = $('<div class="label-with-tooltip pull-left">  <span class="y-label yotpo-user-title yotpo-action-hover" data-type="toggleFade" data-target="yotpo-tool-tip">Verified Buyer</span>  <div class="yotpo-tool-tip yotpo-animation-fade" data-user-type="yotpo-verified-buyer"> <div class="tool-tip-header"> <span>What is a</span> <span class="header-green">Verified Buyer</span> </div> <div class="tool-tip-content"> A Verified Buyer is a user who has purchased the reviewed product through our store. </div> </div> </div>');

// On pagination click, insert that element after each user name, if not already present.
$(document).on("click",".yotpo-pager",function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).find(".yotpo-user-name").each(function(){
      if(!$(this).next().is(".label-with-tooltip")){

        var clone = fake_verified_buyer.clone();
        clone.insertAfter(this);
      }
    });
  },100);
});
```

Comment: I don't like it either, but its not my own site, anyways thanks for the suggestion, I will try it today

Comment: Ok So I tried it and first time it didnt worked, the reason was that the ajax request is made after the function have executed, so I called it in ajaxComplete, but it still didnt worked, then what i did was increase the timeout to 5000, and IT WORKED ! I actually did tried the click method earlier but didnt use setTimeOut, the reason is simple, this function executes and after that content is refreshed so it have no effects on the new contents. Thanks a lot man, I know this is not the right thing, but only if I could help. Thanks again !